# Database login dialogbox pop-up when a crystal report generated in client machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Am using VS 2010 (VB.Net) and MS access 2007 for DB to develop a windows application. Worked well in developing machine. I Installed the application in client machine all the forms were worked well except some reports. When my application started to generate some report it popups the database login window. How to solve this? Actually popup occurs for report which handles 2 tables from DB . Reports with single table working properly.

Pop up asks for:

1.Server name : Shows My developing machine database location

2.Database name : Empty

3.User name : Admin

4.Password : Empty

I tried,

```
          Dim crtableLogoninfos AsNew TableLogOnInfos()

        Dim crtableLogoninfo AsNew TableLogOnInfo()

        Dim crConnectionInfo AsNew ConnectionInfo()

        Dim CrTables As Tables

        Dim CrTable As Table

        With crConnectionInfo

            .DatabaseName = Application.StartupPath & "\sdcartdb.mdb"

            .Password = ""EndWith

        CrTables = Report.Database.Tables

        ForEach CrTable In CrTables

            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo

            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo

            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)

        Next
```

And i tried this too.

```
                    view.SetDatabaseLogon(user, pwd)
```

But still popup exists.

Comment: Does those reports have subreports to?

Comment: No.. Actually am creating reports dynamically but no sub reports.

Comment: Finally I Solved that!! 

Report.DataSourceConnections.Clear()
Report.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection("Server location", "DB name", 1)

 
Now i got **Login failed message** when refreshreport() occurs. But Report generated successfully.
Can anyone help me out of this? **Note : Unfortunately I couldnt post this as answer here. Sorry for that..**